# Generation of pdf file using java

Tags: java, pdf-generation

I am developing a standalone application in Java. I want to generate a pdf file using Java code. I have a display form in which all the details are fetched from database and displayed in the window. Details are Customer Name, Order Details etc.

Now I want to have a button there which says Convert to pdf.
I want to convert this to pdf file with proper alignment and formatting like tables, font etc.

What can be an ideal way to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use iText:

http://itextpdf.com/

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest you to use reporting tool like a [jasperreports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports).

> JasperReports is entirely written in
>   Java and it is able to use data coming
>   from any kind of data source and
>   produce pixel-perfect documents that
>   can be viewed, printed or exported in
>   a variety of document formats
>   including HTML, PDF, Excel, OpenOffice
>   and Word.

Have a look at other open source projects (pdf api):

1. [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)
2. [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) (Toolkit for detecting and extracting metadata and structured text content from various documents using POI and PDFBOX parser libs.)
3. [PDFjet](http://pdfjet.com/os/edition.html)